# VSTS Azure powershell : No default subscription has been designated

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I'm trying to run some azure powershell commands as part of my Visual Studio Team Services build using Azure Resource Manager.

It gives me the following error:

No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzureSubscription -Default  to set the default subscription.

[image: VSTS azure powershell error]

The commands I'm trying to run:

```
$website = Get-AzureWebsite | where {$_.Name -eq 'my-website'}
Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=DeployUrl;]$website.HostNames")
```

When I tried to run it locally, I had to call

```
Add-AzureAccount
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "Visual Studio Premium with MSDN"
```

to get it working, but it is not possible in the VSTS build.

UPDATE:

I've configured it to use the azure classic mode instead of resource manager, at it works. I don't think that it is a feasible solution for production as azure classic mode is obsolete.

Comment: Get-AzureWebSite is the "classic" version of the cmdlet and so requires classic authn.  Get-AzureRmWebApp, is the resource manager cmdlet.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please add an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: You can refer to Eddie's answer.

Comment: Yeah, I think Eddie covered it too - if something could be clarified lmk...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using Azure Resource Manager, please check the things below:

1. Make sure "Azure Resource Manager" service endpoint is added correctly.
2. Use "Get-AzureRmWebApp" command instead of "Get-AzureWebsite" command just as bmoore mentioned.

I have tested it at my side, it works correctly.

My PowerShell script:

```
$website = Get-AzureRmWebApp | where {$_.Name -eq 'eddieapp0930'}
Write-Host $website.HostNames
```

Run from "Azure PowerShell Script" task:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for your question.

If you are using service manager mode(classic mode), the correct cmdlet is:
**Add-AzureAccount

Get-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName “name” | Select-AzureSubscription**

If you are using Resource Manager, the correct cmdlet is:
**Login-AzureRmAccount

Get-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName "name" | Select-AzureRmSubscription**
or just use -SubscriptionId instead of -SubscriptionName.

More information about ASM and ARM, please refer to the link below:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-deployment-model/

If you still have questions, welcome to post back here. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to use both in the same release definition? For example if I wanted to run some ARM templates then call something like `Publish-AzureWebsiteProject` with is an ASM cmdlet. Calling Select-AzureSubscription before calling an ASM cmdlet results in `The subscription id x... doesn't exist`.